# Connecting to CockroachDB from DataGrip

Tags: ssl, datagrip, cockroachdb

Trying to make Postgres connection to CockroachDB with DataGrip but getting this error:

> [08006] The SSLSocketFactory class provided
> com.intellij.execution.rmi.ssl.SslSocketFactory could not be
> instantiated. signed overrun, bytes = 919.

From the DataGrip connection interface:

URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/postgres
```

with port `26257` and with SSL enable

**CA File**

```
/cert/ca.key
```

**Client Certificate File:**

```
/certs/client.root.crt
```

**Client key file:**

```
/client.root.key
```

This setup above doesn't work with DataGrip, but the same certs **works with the CLI**:

```
cockroach cert create-client root --certs-dir=certs --ca-key=/ca.key

cockroach start --certs-dir=certs --store=node1 --listen-addr=localhost:26257 --http-addr=localhost:8080 --join=localhost:26257,localhost:26258,localhost:26259 --background
```

What could be wrong with the DataGrip configuration?

Comment: Could you file an issue in [DataGrip issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE) and attach full IDE log?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to generate the client cert and key in PKCS8 format for Java. This slightly older version of CockroachDB's Java hello world tutorial has guidance that might help: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.1/build-a-java-app-with-cockroachdb#step-3-generate-a-certificate-for-the-maxroach-user.